# Initializing D3D12 debug interfaces failing on laptop with GeForce 960M

Tags: windows, graphics, directx, direct3d, direct3d12

When I try to call D3D12GetDebugInterface or CreateDXGIFactory2 with the flag DXGI_CREATE_FACTORY_DEBUG, the calls are failing on my laptop, but not on my desktop. Other calls work fine on the laptop and I can render stuff -- I just can't initialize the debug layer. The desktop has an oldish GeForce 650 Ti, and the laptop is a Dell XPS15 laptop (latest gen), which has a GeForce GTX 960M. Both have the latest drivers (361.43). Any ideas what could be going wrong?

I posted on the NVIDIA [devtalk forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/905131/directx-and-direct-compute/debug-interfaces-failing-on-laptop/) first, but cross-posted to stackoverflow because the official NVIDIA forum seems pretty dead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Direct3D 12, both the debug layer and the WARP12 device are part of the *Graphics Tools* feature-on-demand which is not part of the default install. You need to enable it on your desktop system.

> This FOD package is specific to your version of Windows 10. If you had it enabled but then upgrade the OS (say from 10240 to 10586) the existing *Graphics Tools* feature-on-demand is disabled. You need to re-enable it so the newer matching version can be installed.

See [Visual C++ Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/31/visual-studio-2015-and-graphics-tools-for-windows-10.aspx)

Comment: This was exactly the solution to my problem. Thanks! To give a little more info to whoever runs into the problem next. Go to System -> Apps & Features -> Manage optional features. Graphics Tools should appear in the list of features you can add from there.